# Flutter Secure Storage Change Route

Tags: flutter, mobile, storage, flutter-dependencies

I have successfully implemented the [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) in my flutter project, when the user writes his email and password, it get's stored, but here is the thing I don't understand. How should I setup screen routes depending if the user has already logged in or not. If it is the same user, so the username and pass are stored in the secure_storage, I want him to go directly to `HomeScreen()`, but if there is a new user that needs to log in, so there is no data in the secure_storage, then I want him sent to `LoginScreen()`. I have done this so far:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login_screen.dart';
import 'home_screen.dart';
import 'components/alarm_buttons.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'welcome_screen';
  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  void readData() async {
    final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    String myPassword = await storage.read(key: "p");
    String myEmail = await storage.read(key: "e");
    print(myEmail);
    print(myPassword);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 2),
        () => Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              storage == null ? LoginScreen.id : HomePage.id,
            ));
    readData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            AlarmButtons(
              buttonColour: Colors.grey,
              buttonText: 'Log In',
              buttonTextColour: Colors.white,
              onButtonPress: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
              },
            ),
            AlarmButtons(
              buttonColour: Colors.white,
              buttonText: 'Sign up',
              buttonTextColour: Colors.grey,
              onButtonPress: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, SignUpScreen.id);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now the problem starts when I want to return to the Welcome Screen (the starting page of my app shown above), naturally it triggers the initState again and I get back to the `HomePage()` again. How can I dispose of that, only triggering that initState when the app starts, so after automatic login I can return to the Welcome Screen without triggering it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initial start something like a SplashScreen (or WelcomeScreen in your case). There you can decide to which screen you want to navigate based on the saved data. Example:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _startApp();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _startApp() async {
    final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    String myEmail = await storage.read(key: "e");
    if (myEmail == null) {
      // TODO Navigate to Login Screen
    } else {
      // TODO Navigate to Home Screen
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Splashscreen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Although you solution maybe cleaner, it does the same, if I wish to return to the SplashScreen in this case, it just reruns the initState method over and over. Or are you suggesting just to make an 'empty' Widget only for this purpose or running the `_startApp()` method? Is this a legitimate practice in Flutter? Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: Its not really an 'empty' widget, because it will be displayed while your data is loading (await storage.read(key: "e")), which will be very only very brief. Therefore I would recommend to use it something like a splashscreen. If you navigate to your screen you should user Navigator.replace. Thereby you cant navigate back to that screen and the initState method will not get called again

Comment: I've tried your solution mate and honestly it works really well, thanks again for the help!